# AS3 Movieclip center rotation and top left X,Y points

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I am creating a flash image cropper. I can resize and move a movieclip containing my image. This movieclip can also be rotated.

The problem I am having is that in order to crop the image properly I need the original X,Y coordinates at the point where the image is at 0 degrees. This is the moveable movieclip I am talking about.

Is there anyway I can take the rotation degree and the current top left X,Y and get the original point at 0 degrees?

Thanks for the assistance

Comment: There really isn't any code to show. I have a movieclip on the stage, I rotate from the center of that MC, the top left X,Y changes when you rotate. I need to figure out the original top left point before rotation (at 0 degrees)

Comment: So how are you rotating? Are you setting `rotation`, `transform.matrix`, or what? See why it's easier to show code?

Comment: I am using a third party transformation manager, thus why no code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you could just let DisplayObject do your job for you:

```
var tempRotation:Number = displayObject.rotation;
displayObject.rotation = 0;
var referencePoint:Point = new Point(displayObject.x, displayObject.y);
displayObject.rotation = tempRotation;
```

Comment: I don't think that will work. I get where you are going with this but I am actually rotating from the center of a display object. as far as I know that uses the upper left hand point.

Comment: I took another look at this and it works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Ah glad you tried it.  As you realized, it most likely depends on container hierarchy, and how those sprites are positioned relative to their parents.  There certainly is a trivial (thought somewhat verbose) pure math approach for a more generic solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just:

- Rotate it to 0 degree.
- Get the new x, y.
- Rotate it back by the angle.

---

BTW, it is always best to rotate by the center. So you have to apply something like

- Translate back by half the width & half the height.
- Rotate it by the angle.
- Translate back...

Comment: I am doing it from the center. I just don't know a formula to calculate my original point. I can't just temporarily rotate it to 0 degrees because the display object is viewable on the stage.